# Redhat 7.3 Sybase 16 (edge) issue with systemctl auto startup process

Tags: redhat, systemctl, sybase

After installing Sybase 16 (Edge) and successfully upgrading a 15.7 instance to Edge, and then trying to add the sybase service with systemctl so that sybase starts up automatically when the Redhat 7 server is booted I am getting this error==> "unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process". Anyone see this before? Any ways to resolve this? Thanks, Will Landstrom

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `systemctl` as root, or at least as a user in the `wheel` group.